# OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty , what is the error?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04

I tried this code for rename a lot directories but I had this error "OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty".

```
import os
for ce in os.listdir("."):
    z = None;
    co = ce;
    if co[0]=="(":
        c = co.find(")",4);
        z = co.replace(ce[0:c+1],"");
        os.rename(ce,z);
        print z
```

Did I do anything wrong?

I have seen that it can be solved if I delete folders with the same name but there are too many and I can not see which, if I try to do it from the script I could delete both, what do you recommend?

Comment: Almost certainly not your actual issue, but the last line mentions the variable `co`, which you haven't used before. Did you mean `ce`?

Comment: The [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html): "Rename the file or directory src to dst. If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised." Perhaps `z` already exists?

Comment: I have changed the name of the variables several times for pleasure, 'ce' is the variable that represents the name of each folder. I have changed some lines in case the problem is by variables, remains the same.

Comment: Ken Y-N ,I do not understand what you want to say

Comment: @Ken Y-N , I try function renames() but don't work, I apologize that I did not catch it well

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the time to rename the folders were some with the same name, then as a solution, distribute the folders in other folders and apply the script, then I put them back in the previous folder and mix those with the same name, code was correct.